# SELECT is not getting unblocked, even after I/O at socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp, unix-socket

I need to communicate using socket between the ring of processes each connected with the master process.
I have connected all the process with the master process and each process is connected to it's left and right neighbour and the master.

When one of the process gets input from the master process to be forwarded to either left neighbour or right neighbour, the process can able to send to it's left neighbour. But its left neighbour is not getting unblocked from the select system call to receive the message. 
I am currently using them on the same machine only.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong in it.
Here is the code for the process.

The Players are connected using socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)

```
while(1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
    FD_SET(s,&read_fd);
    FD_SET(right_sock,&read_fd);
    FD_SET(left_sock,&read_fd);

    int max_sd=s;

    if(right_sock > max_sd)
        max_sd = right_sock;

    if(left_sock > max_sd)
        max_sd = left_sock;

    int activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &read_fd , NULL , NULL , NULL);

    if(FD_ISSET(s, &read_fd))
    {
        len = recv(s, buf1, 5, 0);
        if ( len < 0 ) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"recvhop\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        srand(10);
        ran_no = rand() % 2;
        ran_no = 0;
        strcpy(hopseries,my_id_char);

        if(ran_no == 0)
        {
            printf("Send to Left\n");
            retcode= send(left_sock,&hop_str,strlen(hop_str),0);
            if(retcode == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"recvhop\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            retcode= send(left_sock,&hopseries,1000,0);
            if(retcode == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"recvhop\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else if(ran_no == 1)
        {
            printf("Send to Right\n");
            retcode= send(right_sock,&hop_str,strlen(hop_str),0);
            printf("retcode->%d\n",retcode);
            if(retcode == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"recvhop\n");
                exit(errno);
            }

            retcode= send(right_sock,&hopseries,1000,0);
            if(retcode == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"recvhop\n");
                exit(errno);
            }
        }
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(left_sock, &read_fd))
    {
        printf("LEFT\n");
        // RECEIVE FROM IT'S LEFT NEIGHBOUR
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(right_sock, &read_fd))
    {
        printf("RIGHT\n");
        // RECEIVE FROM IT'S RIGHT NEIGHBOUR
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `strace`. BTW, I prefer `poll` over `select`

Comment: Check the return valu of `select()`.

Comment: Note you did not handle `recv()` returning a zero (i.e. a socket disconnect).  Additionally, `srand()` should be called outside of the `while()` loop, otherwise the value returned by `rand()` will be the same every time.

Comment: Please provide complete set of code to find bug.